# RINEX plotting in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, gps, polynomials

I’m trying to plot data an in order to check my code, I’m making a comparison of the resulting plots with what has already been generated with Matlab. I am encountering several issues however with this:

1. Generally, the parsing of RINEX files works, and the general pattern of the presentation of the data looks similar to that the Matlab scripts plotted. However there are small deviations in data that should become apparent when zooming in on the data i.e. when using a smaller time series, for example plotting over a special 2 hour period, not 24 hours. In Matlab, this small discrepancy can be seen, and a polynomial fitting applied. However for the Python plots (the first plot shown below), the curved line of this two hour period appears “smooth” and does not deviate at all, like that seen in the Matlab script (the second plot shows the blue line as the data, against the red line of the polyfit, hence, the blue line shows a slight discrepancy at x=9.4). The Matlab script is assumed correct, as this deviation is because of an Seismic activity that disrupts the ionosphere temporarily. Please refer to the plots below:

[image: Python plot of data]

[image: Matlab plot of data]

The third plot is in Matlab, where this is simply the polyfit minus the live data.

Therefore, it is not clear just how this data is being plotted on the axes for the Python script, because the data appears to smooth? Nor if my code is wrong (see below) and somehow “smooths” out the data somehow:

```
#Calculating by looping through
            for sv in range(32):
                    sat  = self.obs_data_chunks_dataframe[sv, :]
                    #print "sat.index_{0}: {1}".format(sv+1, sat.index)
                    phi1 = sat['L1'] * LAMBDA_1  #Change units of L1 to meters
                    phi2 = sat['L2'] * LAMBDA_2  #Change units of L2 to meters
                    pr1  = sat['P1']
                    pr2  = sat['P2']


                    #CALCULATION: teqc Calculation
                    iono_teqc = COEFF * (pr2 - pr1) / 1000000 #divide to make values smaller (tbc)
                    print "iono_teqc_{0}: {1}".format(sv+1, iono_teqc)


                    #PLOTTING
                    #Plotting of the data
                    plt.plot(sat.index, iono_teqc, label=‘teqc’)
                    plt.xlabel('Time (UTC)')
                    plt.ylabel('Ionosphere Delay (meters)')
                    plt.title("Ionosphere Delay on {0} for Satellite {1}.".format(self.date, sv+1))
                    plt.legend()
                    ax = plt.gca()
                    ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
                    plt.grid()

                    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
                        plt.savefig(winpath + '\Figure_SV{0}'.format(sv+1))
                    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
                        plt.savefig(macpath + 'Figure_SV{0}'.format(sv+1))

                    plt.close()
```

2. Following on from point 1, the polynomial fitting code below does not run the way I’d like, so I’m overlooking something here. I assume this has to do with the data used upon the x,y-axes but can’t pinpoint exactly what. Would anyone know where I am going wrong here?

   ```
           #Zoomed in plots
           if sv == 19:
               #Plotting of the data
               plt.plot(sat.index, iono_teqc, label=‘teqc’) #sat.index to plot for time in UTC
               plt.xlim(8, 10)
               plt.xlabel('Time (UTC)')
               plt.ylabel('Ionosphere Delay (meters)')
               plt.title("Ionosphere Delay on {0} for Satellite {1}.".format(self.date, sv+1))
               plt.legend()
               ax = plt.gca()
               ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
               plt.grid()

               #Polynomial fitting
               coefficients = np.polyfit(sat.index, iono_teqc, 2)
               plt.plot(coefficients)

               if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
                   #os.path.join(winpath, 'Figure_SV{0}'.format(sv+1))
                   plt.savefig(winpath + '\Zoom_SV{0}'.format(sv+1))
               elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
                   plt.savefig(macpath + 'Zoom_SV{0}'.format(sv+1))

               plt.close()
   ```
3. My RINEX file comprises 32 satellites. However when trying to generate the plots for all 32, I receive:

   IndexError: index 31 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 31

Changing the code below to 31 solves this partly, only excluding the 32nd satellite. I’d like to also plot for satellite 32. The functions for the parsing, and formatting of the data are given below:

```
def read_obs(self, RINEXfile, n_sat, sat_map):
    obs = np.empty((TOTAL_SATS, len(self.obs_types)), dtype=np.float64) * np.NaN
    lli = np.zeros((TOTAL_SATS, len(self.obs_types)), dtype=np.uint8)
    signal_strength = np.zeros((TOTAL_SATS, len(self.obs_types)), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i in range(n_sat):
        # Join together observations for a single satellite if split across lines.
        obs_line = ''.join(padline(RINEXfile.readline()[:-1], 16) for _ in range((len(self.obs_types) + 4) / 5))
        #obs_line = ''.join(padline(RINEXfile.readline()[:-1], 16) for _ in range(2))
        #while obs_line



        for j in range(len(self.obs_types)):
            obs_record = obs_line[16*j:16*(j+1)]
            obs[sat_map[i], j] = floatornan(obs_record[0:14])
            lli[sat_map[i], j] = digitorzero(obs_record[14:15])
            signal_strength[sat_map[i], j] = digitorzero(obs_record[15:16])

    return obs, lli, signal_strength


def read_data_chunk(self, RINEXfile, CHUNK_SIZE = 10000):
    obss = np.empty((CHUNK_SIZE, TOTAL_SATS, len(self.obs_types)), dtype=np.float64) * np.NaN
    llis = np.zeros((CHUNK_SIZE, TOTAL_SATS, len(self.obs_types)), dtype=np.uint8)
    signal_strengths = np.zeros((CHUNK_SIZE, TOTAL_SATS, len(self.obs_types)), dtype=np.uint8)
    epochs = np.zeros(CHUNK_SIZE, dtype='datetime64[us]')
    flags = np.zeros(CHUNK_SIZE, dtype=np.uint8)

    i = 0 #ggfrfg
    while True:
        hdr = self.read_epoch_header(RINEXfile)
        if hdr is None:
            break
        epoch_time, flags[i], sats = hdr
        #epochs[i] = np.datetime64(epoch_time)
        epochs[i] = epoch_time
        sat_map = np.ones(len(sats)) * -1
        for n, sat in enumerate(sats):
            if sat[0] == 'G':
                sat_map[n] = int(sat[1:]) - 1
        obss[i], llis[i], signal_strengths[i] = self.read_obs(RINEXfile, len(sats), sat_map)
        i += 1
        if i >= CHUNK_SIZE:
            break

    return obss[:i], llis[:i], signal_strengths[:i], epochs[:i], flags[:i]


def read_data(self, RINEXfile):
    obs_data_chunks = []

    while True:
        obss, _, _, epochs, _ = self.read_data_chunk(RINEXfile)
        epochs = epochs.astype(np.int64)
        epochs = np.divide(epochs, float(3600.000))

        if obss.shape[0] == 0:
            break

        obs_data_chunks.append(pd.Panel(
            np.rollaxis(obss, 1, 0),
            items=['G%02d' % d for d in range(1, 33)],
            major_axis=epochs,
            minor_axis=self.obs_types
        ).dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=2, how='all'))

        self.obs_data_chunks_dataframe = obs_data_chunks[0]
```

Any suggestions?

Cheers, pymat.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve Qu1 as it was a conversion issue with my calculation that was overlooked, the other two points are however open...